# Plotting Tick Difference

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to plot the tick difference between two bars but I'm running into issues with pine accepting it.

> "Cannot call 'label.new' with argument 'text'='longTicks'. An argument
> of 'series float' type was used but a 'series string' is expected.".

and

> "Cannot call 'label.new' with argument 'x'='longTPCondition'. An
> argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series int' is
> expected."

Here's a simplified version of what I tried:

```
var float longTrade = na
var float longTP = na
var float longTicks = na

if longCondition
    longTrade := close

if longTPCondition
    longTP := close
    longTicks := longTP - longTrade

longticksLabel = label.new(longTPCondition, high, text=longTicks)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code snippet? It looks like a piece of code, so I guess all other things necessary for compilation are already defined.

Comment: "I'm running into issues". Okay but what kind of issues?

Comment: Updated the post to show the exact error I'm getting. And yes, "longCondition" and "longTPCondition" are already defined bools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

longTicks is a value, you must change it to string before using it with label :

```
longticksLabel = label.new(close, high, text=str.tostring(longTicks))
```

longTPCondition is a boolean value, so true or false, not a value, you can use the close value to draw the label next to your asset value :

```
longticksLabel = label.new(close, high, text=longTicks)
```

Comment: in the second example:  
- first parameter of label.new() function is 'x', so use 'close' isn't correct and may cause runtime history depth error;  
- in this example 'longTicks' should be inside str.tostring() too